# Let $Y_{n}$ be a bounded sequence with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma_{n}^{2}$, I want to show the follow

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $Y_{n}$ be a bounded sequence of independet random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma_{n}^{2}$ , Suppose $Y_{n} \xrightarrow{a.e}Y$ and $\sigma_{n}^{2} \to0. $ then show that $Y=\mu \quad a.e$

Comment: 15 questions asked, maybe you could remember to add something personal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**  By the triangle inequality, $$\|Y-\mu\|_{L^2} \leq \|Y-Y_n\|_{L^2}+\|Y_n-\mu\|_{L^2} = \|Y-Y_n\|+ \sigma_n^2.$$ Use dominated convergence in order to show that the first term converges to $0$. Then, $$\|Y-\mu\|_{L^2} = 0,$$ i.e. $Y=\mu$ a.e.

**Remark** A close inspection reveals that we do not need the independence of the random variables. Actually, it suffices to assume that either

- $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of independent bounded random variables with mean $\mu$ converging in probability to some random variable $Y$.

or

- $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of bounded random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma_n^2$ such that $\sigma_n^2 \to 0$ and $Y_n \to Y$ a.e.

In both cases, we have $Y=\mu$ a.e.